# How can I capture the output of an Executable in an image?

Tags: java, windows, screen, capture

I want to capture the output of an exe file as an png or jpg image, i mean the display of that exe.
Is there any command on windows to capture and save as image of an exe output or any other idea that i can do this.

Comment: Do you need to do this programmatically, i.e. from a batch file or program? Or are you just asking how to take a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

There is always the [Robot](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class in Java.  That may be helpful.  Check out [this slightly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305/java-is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-using-java-and-save-it-to-some-sort-of).

Answer (score 1):

The Alt+PrtSc key combination will take a snapshot of the current window and save it into the clipboard. Then you can paste it into your drawing program of choice (MS Paint will do if nothing else is available), and save it to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Alt-PRTSC, then open an image editor and paste.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the Alt + PrintScreen combination on your keyboard will capture the active application window and put it as an image on the clipboard. You can then paste it into Paint or any other application.