# Convert JPanel to image

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel

Is there a way to convert a JPanel (that has not yet been displayed) to a BufferedImage?

thanks,

Jeff

Comment: Well, I give up. I've given you two answers in your last two postings that you've complelely ignore. Good luck with future postings.

Comment: I appreciate the responses and I have not been ignoring them. On this post, ScreenImage wasn't exactly what I was looking for and this method of just painting onto other graphics seemed to be the right direction for me. On the dialog box post, it turned out to be a non-issue and I've been swamped so I haven't been replying to everything. I do appreciate your responses.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From the BufferedImage you can create a graphics object, which you can use to call paint on the JPanel, something like:

```
public BufferedImage createImage(JPanel panel) {

    int w = panel.getWidth();
    int h = panel.getHeight();
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
    panel.paint(g);
    g.dispose();
    return bi;
}
```

You may need to make sure you set the size of the panel first.

Comment: nice, thanks. is there a way i can figure out what the panel size should be (maybe its preferred size)?

Comment: I believe it's preferred size, or current size, as long as it has been rendered already.  There are problems if it has not been rendered already - I cannot remember the exact specifics, but I remember running into similar properties when implementing a printing system.

Comment: Yep, the preferred size works, but as you said, it doesn't render if the panel isn't displayed yet, which doesn't really help me too much. Is there a way to "render" it but not display it on the screen? Basically I'm building a component that needs to get written to an image but not displayed.

Comment: Hmm..that printAll still doesn't work if the component hasn't been made visible yet.

Comment: @JeffStorey How u made  the stuff present on panel visible, in the image created??

Comment: Call panel.doLayout() as the first thing in the method.

Comment: The proposed answer would work correctly in most cases. But what if my panel has an overridden `paint` method, and that method returns different picture each time it is called? In that case the saved image would not be the same as the one which is on the screen at the moment. I wonder, is there a way to save the current image, exactly as it appears on the screen?

Comment: Using `panel.setSize(w,h)` before painting/printing made the picture the correct size even if the component hasn't been visible yet.

Comment: @Karl, call `addNotify()` so the component thinks it has a parent (and can therefore be displayed).

Comment: @ViliusNormantas is that a behaviour you noticed or just an assumption? I fail to see the use can where the paint would be *that* random. In that case though, use [`java.awt.Robot`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-using-java-and-save-it-to-some-sort-of-image). And you're not supposed to override `paint()`, but `paintComponent()`.

Answer (score 4):

> Basically I'm building a component
>   that needs to get written to an image
>   but not displayed

[ScreenImage](http://www.camick.com/java/blog.html?name=screen-image) explains how to do what you want.

---

Relevant section of ScreenImage.java (slightly edited). `layoutComponent` forces all buttons appear in the image.

```
/**
 * @return Renders argument onto a new BufferedImage
 */
public BufferedImage createImage(JPanel panel, int width, int height) {
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
    panel.setSize(width, height); // or panel.getPreferedSize()
    layoutComponent(panel);
    panel.print(g);
    g.dispose();
    return bi;
}

private void layoutComponent(Component component) {
    synchronized (component.getTreeLock()) {
        component.doLayout();

        if (component instanceof Container) {
            for (Component child : ((Container) component).getComponents()) {
                layoutComponent(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer from Tom is basically correct, but invoke `paint()` directly is not recommended, as it is a synchronous call and can interrupt with other operation on the swing thread. Instead of using `paint()`, we should use `print()` instead

```
public BufferedImage createImage(JPanel panel) {

    int w = panel.getWidth();
    int h = panel.getHeight();
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
    panel.print(g);
    g.dispose();
    return bi;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at BasicTableUI. The cell renderer is drawn on image without showing and then drawn on visible table component.