# How to find out the preferred size of a JPanel which is not displayed, according to its content?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am using a JPanel (with several labels inside) to add a dynamic information on a graph. This panel is dynamically created, it is not visible before I use it to draw.

For this, I am using a BufferedImage, and I follow approximately the same steps as described on this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349220/convert-jpanel-to-image). It works good, as long as I specify all sizes (the panel, and its components).

Like asked as well in comments of the referred question, how can I determine the optimal size of this panel? The same operation would be done if this panel was displayed in a regular frame/layout setting.

In my case, how can I "pack", in a way, this panel, so that its size, and size of its content are set to the optimal (determined by the size of labels, then)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suraj and willcodejavaforfood put me on the good track.

Checking what is actually done in a `pack()` method, I see that this is mostly setting the current size to the one returned by `getPreferredSize()`.

From this, I managed to make such solution:

```
// Creating the panel
JPanel lPanel = new JPanel();
//lPanel.setSize(1000, 1000); //default size, not needed anymore
lPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(lPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

//Adding the content
lPanel.add(new JLabel("Blah"));
// etc...

//Adjust the panel to its preferred size
lPanel.setSize(lPanel.getPreferredSize());

//Call the layout method 
//(this will adjust the content components to their correct size and position)
lPanel.doLayout();
```

This method works correctly, and adjusts the panel and its content to the correct size (and answers my question in a simplistic way: "how to find the preferred size? `getPreferredSize()`").

<strike>However, it requires to set the initial size to a large enough size, so that the content fits in, or they won't be put on the layout. This is a bit pity, and not really "clean", but I can't find a way to avoid that, for now.</strike>

**Edit:** Actually, the default size was not necessary, because `getPreferredSize()` returns the correct value, even before calling `doLayout()`. As such, the panel can be set to its proper size before calling the layout method.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer is to call [Window#pack()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack()). This method will automatically set the size of all underlying children to thier preferred sizes(ofcourse this depends on layouts of child containers, for e.g. BorderLayout doesent give a damn about preffered sizes).

So as long as you have set preferred sizes(or min/max sizes in case layouts are like BorderLayout) of your child components, pack() method will be all you need.

**[UPDATE]**
One way is to do is add a [HierarchyListener](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/HierarchyListener.html) to your jpanel and check for [HierarchyEvent#DISPLAYABILITY_CHANGED](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/HierarchyEvent.html#DISPLAYABILITY_CHANGED) events. This event is called when your panel is realized that is ready to be shown(and a parent is available), at this moment you can do:

`SwingUtilities#getWindowAncestor(myPanel).pack();`

Comment: This method would work if my panel was in a window, but it is not. I'm dynamically creating this panel, to draw directly with it. It is not visible in any window before I use it myself. The question is more "how to have the same effect as a *pack()*, without a Window".

Comment: Would putting it in a JFrame and calling pack and then removing the panel work? :)

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood - I've just tried, it does work, but that seems a bit overkill to add a JFrame to the process ;)

Comment: @Gnoupi...even if its in a panel, finally you need to add the panel in a window for the user to see it rt? Then you can call the parentWindow.pack().

Comment: @Suraj - I don't, I use this panel to draw an image, and this image is passed to the graph object. I could eventually use the panel to paint directly over the graph myself, the issue would be the same: this panel won't be added to any container.

Comment: @Gnoupi...i have update my answer...maybe the update is what you need.

Comment: @Suraj - He was talking about his own short solution, to embed it in a temporary JFrame.

Comment: @suraj, like I said, this panel doesn't even have a window ancestor, since it is not added to any window. So it doesn't work, sorry. Thanks for your answer anyway, it put me on the right track ;)