# zxing - export PNG barcode with encoded value

Tags: java, png, zxing

Using zxing, I managed to save a Code39 barcode as PNG but it does display only the bars, no numbers. How could I have the barcode and number in a single PNG?

KI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add the numbers using zxing. You could do something like adding the text yourself to the image, but this might not work flawlessly in all cases without fiddling.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final BufferedImage image = ...

    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont(20f)); // select compatible font
    g.drawString("numbers", 100, 100); // center on your image using image size
    g.dispose();

    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("barcode.png"));
}
```

Alternatively, you could organize all this in a JPanel and then render the panel to image. This would allow you to benefit from layout orientations and fittings. 
[Using something like this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349220/convert-jpanel-to-image)