# Screentoaster, how do they do it?

Tags: java, apache-flex, web-applications, flv, remote-desktop

I need to develop a browser based application that record the user screen, much preferably on flv. Also doing that with java would be perfect.

That's exactly what they accomplished at screentoaster.com , with just a javaWS app. Would anyone have an idea about how they've done it?  Did they use Xuggler?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They appear to be using the Java Robot class, and have embedded the libx264 encoder using a custom build JNI library they used.  Incidentally, given that they are shipping with libx264 and it's a download that installs on client computers (e.g. check the Java caches for the binaries), they should be licensing their code as GPL to compile with libx264.  You may want to follow up with them to get the source.

- Art

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using Java, as described in this answer: [Is there a way to take a screenshot using Java and save it to some sort of image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305/java-is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-using-java-and-save-it-to-some-sort-of) .

You'll need to use a signed Java applet (or Java Webstart app), as unsigned Java code will not have access to the local screen (obvious security problem). Other than that, it should be straightforward.

Comment: hmm, thanks, I sort of knew that. But I'm not sure if the part where I need to convert the stream to flv is straightforward too..