# How to take a screenshot in Java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to take a screenshot using Java and save it to some sort of image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-using-java-and-save-it-to-some-sort-of-image)

How to take a screenshot in Java?

Comment: I answered this question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10796047/876497

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Use [`Robot#createScreenCapture()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29).

```
BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("/screenshot.png"));
```

Comment: Is there anyway to to  position the rectangle?

Answer (score 25):

You can find this code useful. this code will take screenshot in every 10 seconds

```java
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;


public class screen2image
{
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd hh mm ss a");

    public void robo() throws Exception
    {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        BufferedImage screenShot = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
        ImageIO.write(screenShot, "JPG", new File("d:\\"+formatter.format(now.getTime())+".jpg"));
        System.out.println(formatter.format(now.getTime()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        screen2image s2i = new screen2image();
        while(true)
        {
            s2i.robo();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: while(1==1) should probably be replaced with while(true)...