# How to use screen as input in Java

Tags: java, input, screen

I want to be able get an image or bufferedImage of my current screen in my java program. Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490454/how-to-take-a-screenshot-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use the current screenshot in your Java application? First write code to capture the screenshot and then use it in the application.

I found this tutorial useful:

https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/code/216988/java-code-to-capture-your-screen-as-image