# Selenium screenshot in IE

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webpage-screenshot

For screenshot we are using below code

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);                         
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\Screenshot\\Test_Screenshot.png"));
```

It takes the screenshot without any issues in IE but i want to capture the complete screen including taskbar and URL.

Could someone please help or share if it is posible in IE.

Thanks,
Awaiting Reply

Comment: This cannot be done in `Selenium` as browser frame is not a web element.
You can add, for example, `AutoHK` or `AutoIT` script that allow to simulate clicking `Alt`+`PrintScreen` and save image in `Paint`

Comment: ref https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1085

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use screenshot capabilities of Robot instead of selenium: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29

```
BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new    Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("/screenshot.png"));
```

Refer: [How to take a screenshot in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490454/how-to-take-a-screenshot-in-java)

Comment: pls accept it as answer, if the solution resolved your problem.

Comment: i have accepted it as answer!! thanks a lot Parishodak for the help :)