# How to take screenshot on test failure with junit 5

Tags: junit, junit5

Can someone tell me please: how to take a screenshot when test method  fails (jUnit 5). I have a base test class with `BeforeEach` and `AfterEach` methods. Any other classes with @Test methods extends base class.

Comment: Why do you want to take screenshots? And of what exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is possible to write java code that takes screenshots, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490454/how-to-take-a-screenshot-in-java) for example.

But I am very much wondering about the real problem you are trying to solve this way. I am not sure if you figured that yet, but the **main** intention of JUnit is to provide you a framework that runs your tests in various environments.

Of course it is nice that you can run JUnit within your IDE, and maybe you would find it helpful to get a screenshot. But: "normally" unit tests also run during nightly builds and such - in environments where "taking a screenshot" might not make *any* sense!

Beyond that: screenshorts are an **extremely** ineffective way of collecting information! When you have a fail, you should be locking for **textual** log files, html/xml reports, whatever. You want that failing tests generate information that can be easily digested.

So, the real answer here is: step back from what you are doing right now, and re-consider non-screenshot solutions to the problem you actually want to solve!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! But i'm using this framework with appium and running tests on ios real devices. It would be usefull to make screenshots to see, what tha problem was.

Comment: When doing E2E tests with for example JUnit + Selenium it IS very useful to have both textual information & a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to take screen shots for JUnit test failes/passes, rather the recommended way is to generate various reports (Tests Passed/Failed Report, Code coverage Report, Code complexity Report etc..) automatically using the below tools/plugins.

You can use **Cobertura maven plugin** or **Sonarqube code quality tool** so that these will automatically generate the reports for you.

You can look [here](http://www.mojohaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/) for **Cobertura-maven-plugin** and [here](http://www.sonarqube.org/) for **Sonarqube** for more details.

**You need to integrate these tools with your CI (Continuous Integration) environments and ensure that if the code is NOT passing certain quality (in terms of tests coverage, code complexity, etc..) then the project build (war/ear) should fail automatically.**

Answer (score 0):

I use junit 5 and selenium. (take screenshot using junit 5 and selenium)
I did that through extension (extension from junit 5, making screenshot using selenium), here is my test class:

```java
public class MyTests2 {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static WebDriver getDriver(){
        return driver;
    }

    @RegisterExtension
    static RunnerExtentsion2 extentsion2 = new RunnerExtentsion2(MyTests2::getDriver);

    @BeforeEach
    private void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @AfterEach
    private void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void emptyBothNameAndPassAuthNegaTest() {
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com/");
        throw new NoSuchElementException("my exception");
    }
}
```

Here is my screenshot taker class:

```java
public class RunnerExtentsion2 implements AfterTestExecutionCallback {
    private Supplier<WebDriver> driverSupplier;

    public RunnerExtentsion2(Supplier<WebDriver> driverSupplier){
        this.driverSupplier = driverSupplier;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTestExecution(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        Boolean testResult = context.getExecutionException().isPresent();
        if (context.getExecutionException().isPresent()) {
            System.out.println("screenshot");
            driverSupplier.get().get(...);
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**