# How to capture screenshot using a java program wrapped as windows service

Tags: java, windows, service, screenshot

I have a java program to capture screenshot on Windows. Here is part of the code. It is generating a black image when wrapped by YAJSW and run as a windows service.

```
BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", file.toFile());
```

I know this is due to some limitation of windows service. But is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I found another post on the same topic [How to take a screenshot in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490454/how-to-take-a-screenshot-in-java)

Try the following code from the second answer :
If this doesnt work, it would exclude the possibility, that one hidden part of your code is responsible for the bug.

> ```
> import java.awt.Rectangle;
> import java.awt.Robot;
> import java.awt.Toolkit;
> import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
> import java.io.File;
> import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
> import java.text.DateFormat;
> import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
> import java.util.*;
>
>
> public class screen2image
> {
>     SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd hh mm ss a");
>
>     public void robo() throws Exception
>     {
>         Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
>         Robot robot = new Robot();
>         BufferedImage screenShot = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
>         ImageIO.write(screenShot, "JPG", new File("d:\\"+formatter.format(now.getTime())+".jpg"));
>         System.out.println(formatter.format(now.getTime()));
>     }
>
>     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
>     {
>         screen2image s2i = new screen2image();
>         while(1==1)
>         {
>             s2i.robo();
>             Thread.sleep(10000);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Hope it helps you !
If this doesnt work, you should probably check your Windows/Java installation...