# How can I execute CMD commands with java?

Tags: java

I want my java program to do the following things:

Access cmd and execute the commands: "d:", "cd D:\Java Projects\imageProject", "screenshot-cmd"

I tried to google that and found some code examples but none of them worked because I probably have no idea what i'm doing.

This is what I have now:

```
static void imageFromCMD(){
     ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                "cmd.exe", "d:", "cd D:\\Java Projects\\imageProject",
                "screenshot-cmd");
     Process p = builder.start(); 
}
```

that code doesn't fail but i'm not getting the output (image in the dir) that i expect

I guess I'm missing the "sending" part, but how exactly can I do it?

Comment: what is `screenshot-cmd` ?

Comment: just an `.exe` i downloaded from internet that takes screenshot and saves it when pressed/run from cmd

Comment: Why not just use Java to take the Sceen-shot

Comment: Maybe https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture(java.awt.Rectangle)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490454/how-to-take-a-screenshot-in-java

Comment: I know about `Robot`, however I had few problems with it and its slower, i prefer the cmd method

Comment: do you tried to get the `inputstream` from `Process p` after you launched it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
Path workingDir = Paths.get("D:\\Java Projects\\imageProject");
processBuilder.directory(workingDir.toFile()); // Edited here
processBuilder.command(".\\screenshot-cmd");
try {
    processBuilder.start();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

An alternative option is to give the full path to the executable like so when creating a `ProcessBuilder`

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("D:\\Java Projects\\imageProject\\screenshot-cmd");
try {
    processBuilder.start();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

One thing to note is that if you don't set the working directory when creating a `ProcessBuilder`, the directory of your main process is the working directory by default (basically from where your main class is being invoked), maybe try looking in there to see if the screenshots are being saved to that location

Comment: now it says "cannot run screenshot-cmd in the directory", but it works fine when i'm doing it manually and I made sure its the right name

Comment: What kind of exception did you get? `SecurityException` ?

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "screenshot-cmd" (in directory "D:\Java Projects\imageProject"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: That's super interesting, can you try this `processBuilder.command(".\\screenshot-cmd");`, basically saying that that command should be found in the current working directory

Comment: Please try my latest edit attempt, if that doesn't fix it either, I really have no idea why. Also, does the executable have `.exe` extension? If so, you must include the extension as well in the `ProcessBuilder` configurations

Comment: ok I didn't get any error for this one, but nothing happen. the command suppose to create a `.png` file but it didn't

Comment: Maybe it didn't save the screenshot to the current directory? If you don't set the working directory when creating a `ProcessBuilder` the directory of your main process is the working directory by default (basically from where your main class is being invoked), maybe try looking in there

Answer (score 1):

Here is my program to check the Java version. Hope this help.

```
import java.io.*; 
public class RunCMDByJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "java -version");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = pb.start();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            line = br.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First find out the exact cmd.exe line to run and then stuff it into a ProcessBuilder, like this

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "cd /tmp & dir")
```

Please note that all commands should be passed to cmd.exe as one single argument.

Comment: What happens if the pc is Mac? meaning does not have cmd.exe ?

Comment: Since the question is on CMD, my understanding is that this must be a Windows.

Comment: Oh, yea, my bad.