# how can screenshot be taken online using java?

Tags: java, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Is there a way to take a screenshot using java and save it to some sort of image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305/java-is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-using-java-and-save-it-to-some-sort-of)

hi
  I am using Ubuntu,I am trying to write code in java.
  I want to take screenshots dynamically using java.
  Please help me,how to do it.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "online" and "dynamically"?

Comment: Do you need screenshots of the desktop/os or of your application only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See java.awt.Robot.

(+ 11 characters for the politburo - ignore this comment).

Comment: "http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html" is 64 characters. Just saying.

Comment: If you like to suggest to download something - feel free to do so. If I wanted to suggest to download it, I would have done so. Playing carnival in Venice, and pretending to just naturally always use 30 characters at least is not, what I like to do, when I get angry about such rules. Please ignore this comment entirely. Thanks.

Comment: You suggested a class. I linked to the Javadocs of that class, that's all.

Comment: Well, but the link is broken, you have to remove the trailing, maybe the leading '"'. In FF, removing the trailing quote was sufficient. 137 charcters.

Comment: I actually just raised [a bug on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89137/links-in-quotes-are-escaped-improperly-in-comments) that links in quotation marks don't work.