# Converting gridview into image

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to convert gridview into image and save it to localdisk in asp.net 3.5.I donot have any idea how to do it.

Can anyone please suggest something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192799/html-to-image-in-javascript-or-python

Comment: You can use Java applet. Check the below url:

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305/java-is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-using-java-and-save-it-to-some-sort-of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following links may help you:

[Convert a DataGridView to a Bitmap](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/DGV2BMP01182007020129AM/DGV2BMP.aspx)

[Exporting a DataGridView to an Excel/PDF/image file by using Reporting Services report generation - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/reporting-services/ReportExporters_WinForms.aspx)

Comment: Its not converting, instead taking screenshot. Rows won't be added, if are behind scrollbars.

Answer (score 1):

Why you would want to convert it into an image, I'm not sure. If the gridview has paging, you'd have to capture each page like that. A better way is to export it into like Excel or something. Here is code to do that:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public class GridViewExportUtil
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    /// <param name="gv"></param>
    public static void Export(string fileName, GridView gv)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader(
            "content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                //  Create a table to contain the grid
                Table table = new Table();

                //  include the gridline settings
                table.GridLines = gv.GridLines;

                //  add the header row to the table
                if (gv.HeaderRow != null)
                {
                    GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(gv.HeaderRow);
                    table.Rows.Add(gv.HeaderRow);
                }

                //  add each of the data rows to the table
                foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
                {
                    GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(row);
                    table.Rows.Add(row);
                }

                //  add the footer row to the table
                if (gv.FooterRow != null)
                {
                    GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(gv.FooterRow);
                    table.Rows.Add(gv.FooterRow);
                }

                //  render the table into the htmlwriter
                table.RenderControl(htw);

                //  render the htmlwriter into the response
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Replace any of the contained controls with literals
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="control"></param>
    private static void PrepareControlForExport(Control control)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < control.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            Control current = control.Controls[i];
            if (current is LinkButton)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as LinkButton).Text));
            }
            else if (current is ImageButton)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as ImageButton).AlternateText));
            }
            else if (current is HyperLink)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as HyperLink).Text));
            }
            else if (current is DropDownList)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text));
            }
            else if (current is CheckBox)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as CheckBox).Checked ? "True" : "False"));
            }

            if (current.HasControls())
            {
                GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(current);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Simply call the static Export method with the name of the XLS file and the GridView:

```
GridViewExportUtil.Export("MyFile.XLS", myGridView);
```

Comment: They asked for image, not excel file.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Java applet. Check the below url:

[Is there a way to take a screenshot using java and save it to some sort of image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305/java-is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-using-java-and-save-it-to-some-sort-of)