# How to save GridView output to an Image?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, image

I am developing a Dashboard for a web application , dashboard shows various Chart (Telerik RadChart) Images and GridView Tables. See below image:

[image])

To increase performance of dashboard loading we are implementing Caching for dashboard.

We are generating jpeg images from RadChart everyday and storing in a folder on server, these images are available whole day in caching, next day they gets dirty and regenerated on Dashboad load.

I am able to successfully export RadChart to images but don't know how to export GridView output as images.

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the best way to go about this would be to:

1. Generate the gridview as html. You may have to manually do this by looping through your data and outputting it as an html table.
2. Render your outputted html as an image.

Here is a [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/html2image.aspx) that explains converting html to images in c#.

Otherwise have a look through this answer [Converting gridview into image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771645/converting-gridview-into-image). It seems your question is quite common.

Comment: how can I convert only grid output to html? , grid is a part of a user control

Comment: in the page you can see there are more control than gridview, I tried your way but it has limit that it can render gridview as Response only, I want only the html output and I'll add it to parent control and create one image of all these control