# Exporting GridView with Data to Image in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have to export grid view control to image.I have tried to convert grid view to bitmap for that i referred this [Link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/scottlysle/dgv2bmp01182007020129am/dgv2bmp.aspx),But i failed to achieve the task.I also referred this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700722/how-to-save-gridview-output-to-an-image) and [asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1370129.aspx/1) links,But not yet achieved my task. Is this possible to export grid view control with data to image.If yes,How can i do.please help me out.Make sure i am using asp.net gridview control.

Comment: What did not work? Where exactly did you fail? Your first link refers to a `DataGridView`. That is a winforms control, and will not work in asp.net.

Comment: yes,I know first link refers to win forms only.My question is how to achieve in asp.net.Is this possible.I worked around a day.But result is Nill

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771645/converting-gridview-into-image

Comment: Is it possible yes. The stackoverflow link does guild you on how to do it. But a simpler solution would be to use a component like ReportViewer bound to a DataSet, that can output images by default.

Comment: @BeginnerCoder I started my task from that link only.Any way thanks for your comment.I hope some one will give possible reply.Thanq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To export a gridview to a image,

```
1.First export gridview data to pdf. 
2.Then  convert it into image.
```