# Is there any other way of obtaining a screenshot of the entire screen? (Java)

Tags: java, awt, awtrobot

Besides using the createScreenCapture() method of the java.awt.Robot class, is there any other way of obtaining a screenshot of the entire screen?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the way you mentioned?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-using-java-and-save-it-to-some-sort-of-image/10796047#10796047

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you might be able to call JNI code to do this, or find / write an external command-line program that grabs the screenshot and that can be run via `System.exec`.  However, I don't think either of these is a good idea ...

The `Robot` class *should* do what you want.  If it doesn't, you'll get a better outcome if you tell us what the actual problem with it is.  The chances are that someone else has encountered it and knows a solution.