# How can you screenshot a users browser?

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Take a screenshot of a webpage with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript)

I'm looking to screenshot a users browser and upload it to a server in the simplest way possible.

I've been told that a transparent flash movie can screenshot the page, but else where heard the opposite.

Is this possible with a java-applet?

Any suggestions on how to do this would great.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, as I 'm not restricting it to JS and need it to work cross browser.

Comment: [`html2canvas`](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) works on all browsers. (with support of canvas)

Comment: This isn't a screenshot unfortunately; it's unlikely to work with broken pages

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-using-java-and-save-it-to-some-sort-of-image