# displaying a web page with HTTP request

Tags: java

I was searching some examples about sending HTTP requests in order to display web page on my browser by using java. I couldn't find a simple example for that. Do you have any suggestions ? Where should I look for a good example with explanations ? Thank you

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean that you want to create java application that runs on client side, opens user's default browser and shows web page in it?

Comment: For now yes, I just want to see basics of http requests and how to display a web page on my browser by sending http request. As you said it is a java app and runs on client side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use
`java.net.URL, java.net.URLConnection, java.io.InputStream, org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils` to manage HTTP requests in a java application

Here is an example class -

```
public class HttpUtil
{
    static URL url;
    static URLConnection urlConn;
    static DataOutputStream out;
    static BufferedReader input;

    static public String get(String _url)
    {
        try 
        {
            url = new URL(_url.replace(" ", "%20"));

            InputStream input = url.openStream();
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(input, writer);
            return writer.toString();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "ERROR: " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    static public String post(String _url, String postData)
    {
        String result = "";

        try
        {
            url = new URL(_url);

             urlConn = url.openConnection();
             urlConn.setDoInput(true);
             urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
             urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
             urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

             out = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());
             String content = postData;

             out.writeBytes(content); // send the data

             out.flush();
             out.close();

             DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(urlConn.getInputStream());
             input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

             String str;

             while ( (str = input.readLine() ) != null )
             {
                 result = result + str + "\n";
             }

             input.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
            return null;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

You can also fire up a web browser in java by using this little snippet -

```
URI url = new URI("file:/" + ur); // or an absolute path to a website http://google.com/

Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url);
```

Comment: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils cannot be resolved, I think it can be because of my eclipse version. I'm using Juno

Comment: If you aren't using Maven, download it from http://commons.apache.org/io/download_io.cgi and add the .jar file the download comes with, to your build path.  If using Maven, this might help - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.2

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Desktop.browse("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844363/displaying-a-web-page-with-http-request");
```

---

**See Also**

- [API Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29)

Comment: The `java.awt` package never stops to surprise me. (http://stackoverflow.com/q/58305/1374678)