# Screen capture with Java?

Tags: java, screen-capture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to take a screenshot using Java and save it to some sort of image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-using-java-and-save-it-to-some-sort-of-image)

I want to capture the screen in a particular application or a particular window. I am thinking of doing it in Java. If Java is okay for this purpose, then which API/Classes can I use ?

Comment: Do the [Robot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/58326/680925)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Java [Robot#createScreenCapture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) API.