# How to scan and compare images in Java

Tags: java, image

I'm wondering if there is any possibility to compare images from my local disc with images placed in flash application located on a website. There is no possibility to get direct link to those images from the website, so I need method to scan image situated on exact coordinates. It would be great if it works fine with Robot class because I need to move mouse pointer remotely after this comparision.

Comment: Have you checked the OpenCV library ? http://opencv.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305/

Comment: @Joe Elleson well it's not bad solution but i forgot to mention that i care about execution time, so capturing and saving all images is rather bad idea

Answer (score 1):

It is possible,  but there are a lot of methods to compare images, depending on what result do you need.

- do you need exact comparison?  ( then compute hash over all the pixels )
- do you need some dergee of similarity (compute invariant  moments and calculate distance)

For the invariant moments you may use our  pure java ocr library:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/

( tricky part is choice of proper set of moments )