# take screenshot and save it on server using servlet and jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, screenshot

I want to implement functionality as below using JSP and servlet. Please give me some suggestion.

1. user logs-in to JSP page.
2. JSP page now runs thread that continuously take screen shot of
   client desktop no meter that page is display or not. (for taking
   screen shot client must be login to JSP page)
3. each screen shot save to image folder on server and its path will
   store to DB.

Comment: Jsp works in the server side and you need to catch client desktop. I think you need to do this with js that runs in client side.

Comment: JSP runs on server side ,how could you run it on client side ? And suppose it captures screenshot but jsp page runs in web browser. So, what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Perhaps it could explore the folder desktoop and send the list of folfer and app that contains.

Comment: I guess js can do just a screenshot of opened page. If you need a screenshot of full screen, than, I guess, you have to use applet or activex.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a java applet that [makes screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-using-java-and-save-it-to-some-sort-of-image) and saves image files to a temporary folder. Embed this applet into your JSP page.
2. Use AJAX-calls on your JSP-page to grab these image files from local temporary folder and upload them to the server [via POST-requests](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/ajax-post-method-example-using-javascript-jquery/).