# Is it possible to make JUnit tests using Sikuli take a screenshot on failure?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, sikuli

I am using JUnit and Sikuli to run automated GUI tests. I want to take a screenshot whenever an error occurs with the test (usually this is a FindFailed exception). Specifically, I am hoping to integrate these screenshots with the HTML reports generated by JUnit. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: I am not familiar with Sikuli, but you can take a screen shot with java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-using-java-and-save-it-to-some-sort-of-image

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that with sikuli by using the shutil module. The code will look something like this:

import shutil
capture(region)

region = SCREEN in this case, or you can also specify a region. You can throw this code in your catch block to get the screenshot when there is an error.

In my project, I have a tracker class, that will generate log file and every time I put out a log with the word "ERROR" in it, I call this to get a screenshot, that way, I will have a screenshot of every error, and not just the findfailed exception.