# Java Screenshots and memory usage

Tags: java, awt, bufferedimage, ram, awtrobot

I have a question about screenshot in java: exist a library for take screenshot and save them for java?
Now I'm using buffered images and AWT robot (you can find the repo here : [GitHub](https://github.com/KSUploader)), but them have some memory leak and use a lot of memory (foreach screen it take the memory use increment about ~ 40 MB).
Can you give me a library or some trick for take screenshot using less memory as possible?

Here the code that i use for screenshot, but it has the problem mentioned.(It take a partial screen)

```
ImageIO.write(new Robot().createScreenCapture(Main.so.getScreenBounds()).getSubimage(
                                partialScreen.selectionBounds.x,
                                partialScreen.selectionBounds.y,
                                partialScreen.selectionBounds.width,
                                partialScreen.selectionBounds.height), "png", tempFile);
```

So much thanks!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: @Trobbins i know that, i ask infact an help for reduce memory consumpion.

Comment: _"exist a library for ... ?"_ and _"Can you give me a library..."_

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). But while I'm here, don't create a new `Robot` for every screenshot!  Create it once and store it as a class member.  BTW - from things you wrote it seems the code needs to take more than one.  screenshot and possibly many.  Is this for a 'movie' of the screen or for 'screen sharing', or something else?  Please flesh out the detail of what all this is trying to achieve (the 'application feature').

Comment: @AndrewThompson The application is a screen sharing tool, like puush and screencloud, a simple MCVE is a thing like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-using-java-and-save-it-to-some-sort-of-image), just add an Thread.sleep and see the memory usage in the task manager (about 30 MB, what!?). The problem i think is the buffered image, because analyzing the application with a profiler you can see that the memory is used by a lot  of int[] array.

Comment: *"and see the memory usage in the task manager"* A developer can pay too much attention to the task manager.  Does the application throw `OutOfMemoryError`?

Comment: @AndrewThompson The application doesn't throw outofmemory, but it's not possible that after some screenshots(full screen and partial) and file uploads it consume about ~ 300 MB of memory.

Comment: *"The application doesn't throw outofmemory,"*  Then don't stress about it.  The Windows task manager is known to provide information that scares developers (most users don't know it exists) but is not really accurate.

Comment: Why do you first capture the entire screen, then get a subimage of that? If you want to use less memory, just capture the `partialScreen.selectionBounds` right away.

Comment: @haraldK your solution work only on pc with only one monitor, i've already tried it

Comment: @SergiX44 Maybe because the selection bounds is in a different coordinate space? Then calculate the correct bounds before capturing the screen shot. The main point remains the same: Don't capture more than you need.

Comment: @haraldK yes, but how i can know the correct order of the monitors? this is the problem.

Comment: How did you know that before? Or, if you didn't know it before, why do you think you need it now? You just need to calculate a sub-rectangle from a larger rectangle, the same way getSubimage does.