# How to take webpage screenshot in Java?

Tags: java, jsoup, htmlunit

I want to take Screenshot of the web-page at Runtime while screen-scraping with HtmlUnit or Jsoup in Java.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-using-java-and-save-it-to-some-sort-of-image)?

Comment: @npinti I flagged it as dup

Comment: @moffeltje: Seems like it, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

HtmlUnit does not render the elements. It is GUI-less (headless) browser.

Please find sample code using WebDriver/Selenium [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3423347/184201).

Answer (score 0):

This item may be helpful. It uses `java.awt.Robot` to take a screen shot and save it to disk.

[Previous Answer - Java Screen Shot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-using-java-and-save-it-to-some-sort-of-image)

Answer (score -1):

Try this one Robot#createScreenCapture().

```
BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(newRectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("/screenshot.png"));
```