# Could selenium take screenshot for all active desktop entirely?

Tags: java, linux, selenium

Could selenium take screenshot not for page in browser only,  but for all active desktop entirely? I just need to  know the dimensions of the remote screen. We use linux with Xvfb for UI tests

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-using-java-and-save-it-to-some-sort-of-image)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWT class Robot to capture the screen in between the selenium webdriver code. I don't think selenium has any own API to capture screen.

```
    BufferedImage screenBuffer = new Robot().createScreenCapture(
               new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()) );
    File file = new File("MyScreen.jpg");
    ImageIO.write(screenBuffer, "jpg", file);
```