# Take screenshot including Task bar using Selenium in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I need to take the screenshot of the page(web application) including Windows Taskbar in Selenium using java. Can anyone please tell me how to do it.

I am using below code to take the screenshot however i need to take a screenshot of Taskbar too. Basically i want to recreate **"Print Screen (PrntSc)"** functionality using Selenium.

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\screenshot.png"));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to take a screenshot using Java and save it to some sort of image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-using-java-and-save-it-to-some-sort-of-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned this question has already been asked.
However, just for the convenience, here is the solution.

Simply using Selenium, will let you take screenshot only of the browser DOM window. You'll be needing Robot API for the requirement, which is native to Java, no third-party API required.

The code is as below:

```
Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
BufferedImage screenFullImage = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);
ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, "png", new File("./Screenshots/"+ FILENAME));
```

Selenium just works on the browser DOM window, which fails to operate on anything outside the DOM window.

For more information on this, please refer this thread: [Is there a way to take a screenshot using Java and save it to some sort of image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-using-java-and-save-it-to-some-sort-of-image)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
public static void captureScreen() throws AWTException, UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException{

        Robot robot = new Robot();

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);

        Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();


        BufferedImage img = (BufferedImage) cb.getData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor);
        File file = new File("C:/newimage.png");
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", file);

    }
```