# How can you get the handle of a chrome process in java using JNA

Tags: java, google-chrome, process, jna, hwnd

I am new to JNA, and I need to take a screenshot of a chrome window using java and JNA, I already have the function for taking screenshots of a given window using this code:

```
  public BufferedImage capture(WinDef.HWND hWnd) {

    WinDef.HDC hdcWindow = User32.INSTANCE.GetDC(hWnd);
    WinDef.HDC hdcMemDC = GDI32.INSTANCE.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow);



    WinDef.RECT bounds = new WinDef.RECT();
    User32Extra.INSTANCE.GetClientRect(hWnd, bounds);

    int width = bounds.right - bounds.left;
    int height = bounds.bottom - bounds.top;

    WinDef.HBITMAP hBitmap = GDI32.INSTANCE.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcWindow, width, height);

    WinNT.HANDLE hOld = GDI32.INSTANCE.SelectObject(hdcMemDC, hBitmap);
    GDI32Extra.INSTANCE.BitBlt(hdcMemDC, 0, 0, width, height, hdcWindow, 0, 0, WinGDIExtra.SRCCOPY);

    GDI32.INSTANCE.SelectObject(hdcMemDC, hOld);
    GDI32.INSTANCE.DeleteDC(hdcMemDC);

    WinGDI.BITMAPINFO bmi = new WinGDI.BITMAPINFO();
    bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -height;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = WinGDI.BI_RGB;

    Memory buffer = new Memory(width * height * 4);
    GDI32.INSTANCE.GetDIBits(hdcWindow, hBitmap, 0, height, buffer, bmi, WinGDI.DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    image.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, buffer.getIntArray(0, width * height), 0, width);

    GDI32.INSTANCE.DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    User32.INSTANCE.ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdcWindow);

    return image;

}
```

then I use the following code to save the bufferedImage:

```
     BufferedImage image;

     WinDef.HWND hWnd = User32.INSTANCE.FindWindow(null, "notepad - untitled");
                image = capture(hWnd);
                File outputfile = new File("image.jpg");
                try {
                    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputfile);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

this works for some applications, e.g. notepad but not for chrome, for chrome it just throws a Illegal Argument Exception cause the program is trying to capture a screenshot with a width and height which are basically 0 since the process wasn't found, the full exception is this:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Allocation size must be greater than zero
at com.sun.jna.Memory.<init>(Memory.java:111)
at de.xliquid.stadiarpc.Main.capture(Main.java:103)
at de.xliquid.stadiarpc.Main$1.run(Main.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.KeyboardShortcutsHandler.processAccelerators(KeyboardShortcutsHandler.java:347)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.KeyboardShortcutsHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(KeyboardShortcutsHandler.java:163)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3964)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3910)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2040)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2501)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:217)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:149)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$357(GlassViewEventHandler.java:248)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:247)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:546)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:966)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.java:177)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I tried using the current title of chrome but that didn't work, and I think the best solution would be to just get the handle of chrome's first tab. Sadly I don't really know where to start here. Can anyone tell me what I could do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I commend your courage cause this JNA.. didnt it break your machine??

Comment: Yes this code is, well, not the best solution but it works for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JNA's [`WindowUtils`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.6.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/WindowUtils.html) class can be helpful here.  The `getAllWindows()` method will return a `List<DesktopWindow>` where each [`DesktopWindow`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.6.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/DesktopWindow.html) instance includes both a title (to match up with your Chrome process) and the `HWND` handle to that window.

The `DesktopWindow` also has a `Rectangle` with location and size dimensions, so you can copy the appropriate dimensions from the desktop itself, such as this simple one-liner:

```java
BufferedImage screenShot = new Robot().createScreenCapture(rectangle);
```

Answers to [this StackOverlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-using-java-and-save-it-to-some-sort-of-image) identify multiple other options for taking a screenshot of the entire window; simply substitute the `Rectangle` you derive from the `DesktopWindow` class appropriately (or use your own code above with the rectangle's dimensions).

Alternately, if you don't need all the information from the `WindowUtils` class, you could more directly use the WinAPI's [`EnumWindows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) function to directly iterate the windows and capture only the information that you need.  This is the function `WindowUtils` uses internally, so its source code would be a good starting point to simplify from.

Comment: "Answers to this StackOoverlow Question identify multiple other options for taking a screenshot of the entire window": dont tell me they are all relying on robot!

Comment: No, they're not. That was just a convenient one-liner. :) Also, "Oops" on the typo.